# Скрыть/показать коллекцию, как работает hide(), click в цикле for in

Tags: javascript, raphael

Элементарная казалось бы задача, бьюсь второй день.
Отрисовываю объекты через цикл for in, понадобилось опция скрыть/показать весь набор элементов, получается скрывать только один. Это raphaeljs, но ситуация думаю типовая в общем для js.

```
var balls = {
  ball_01: {
    name: "ball01",
    x: 100,
    y: 206,
  },
  ball_02: {
    name: "ball02",
    x: 263,
    y: 206,
  },
  ball_03: {
    name: "ball03",
    x: 200,
    y: 206,
  }
};
        for (var circle in balls) {
          var allcircle = p.circle(balls[circle].x, balls[circle].y, 10).attr(styleButton);
            button.click(function(){
        allcircle.hide(); //скрывает один элемент, хотя allcircle в консоль выводит всю коллекцию
    });
    };
```

Полностью код тут - https://jsfiddle.net/jfw0vo5c/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю можно попробовать разделить создание и удаление например вот так

```
var allcircle = [];
for (var circle in balls) {
 allcircle[circle] = p.circle(balls[circle].x, balls[circle].y, 10).attr(styleButton);

};
button.click(function(){
for( var tt in allcircle){
allcircle[tt].hide();
}
  });
```